# Creating groups in BizTalk Server 2009 config

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I am trying to creat groups with the BTS 2009 COnfiguration console, but I am getting the following error:

> Failed to create Management database "BizTalkMgmtDb" on server...

What causes this problem?

Comment: BTS 2009 needs SQL Sever 2008 standard (not R2). Are you using this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTS 2009 needs SQL Sever 2008 standard (not R2).

Comment: I realise I have to install BizTalk 2010. Here is my setup: Windows Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: You can also run SQL 2008 in parallel with 2008R2 if you want to use BTS 2009.